# representation of spinors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, hilbert-space, spinors

I am trying to get from the abstract representation of Spinors,
as wave functions $|\Psi \rangle$ in the base of tensors products $| S_z \rangle \otimes | x \rangle$ of eigenvectors of the spin operator $\hat S_z$  and position operator $ \hat x$ to the representation in wave function form: $ \begin{pmatrix}{\Psi_+(x) \\ \Psi_-(x)} \end{pmatrix}$.

I seem to be missing something key. I would really apprechiate some help with this. Here is where i go wrong:

$$ \int dx \sum_{s_z} (| x \rangle \otimes | S_z\rangle) \; (\langle x|  \otimes \langle S_z|) |\Psi \rangle=\int dx \sum_{s_z} (| x \rangle \otimes | S_z\rangle) \; (\langle x|\Psi \rangle  \otimes \langle S_z|\Psi \rangle) 
$$
which i would normally  read as 
$$ =  \int dx \sum_{s_z} (| x \rangle \otimes | S_z\rangle) \; ( \Psi(x)  \; \langle S_z|\Psi \rangle) \\ =\int dx  (| x \rangle \otimes | +\rangle) \; ( \Psi(x)  \; \begin{pmatrix}{1 \\ 0} \end{pmatrix})+(| x \rangle \otimes | -\rangle) \; ( \Psi(x)  \; \begin{pmatrix}{0 \\ 1} \end{pmatrix}) $$

which then if i leave the summation over the base vectors out gives $ \begin{pmatrix}{\Psi(x) \\ \Psi(x)} \end{pmatrix}$ which is exactly not what i want. Since it is the same wave function in both components, what am i doing wrong here?

How do i get different wave functions for the different components using the dirace formalism? I would really be glad about some Tipps.

Comment: The components of the wave function are defined by $(\langle x| \otimes \langle s|)|\Psi\rangle= \Psi_s (x)$ where $s$ labels the spin state

Comment: Soory pressed enter by mistake. So what i still dont understand is this: $ \hat S_z (\Psi_+(x) + \Psi_-(x)) = {\hbar \over 2 }((\Psi_+(x) - \Psi_-(x)) ) $ how do we get to the vector then?

Comment: Oh well i guess $\begin{pmatrix}{1 & 0  \\ 0 & -1 } \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}{\Psi_+(x) \\ \Psi_-(x)} \end{pmatrix}$ would be a valid representation of that right? (I have no idea why the latex is wrong)

Comment: maybe someone knows what is wrong? ^^ sorry i can not for the life of me find it